# Unable to set up Raid during Kubuntu 15.04 installation

Tags: kubuntu, 15.04, raid

According to the installation documentation one should be able to choose something along the lines of 'physical space for raid' when choosing manual partitioning during installation but the option does not seen to show up for me. Does anyone have an idea why this could be the case or how to set up Raid with Kubuntu?

[image: physical volume for raid not present]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so the trick seems to be:

- use try Kubuntu (rather than install)
- connect to internet
- apt-get install mdadm
- create/assemble your raid array (e.g., mdadm --assemble --scan --verbose)
- start the installation
- the raid array should now show up in the dropdown list
- don't forget to install mdadm after the installation has finished but before you reboot (earlier you installed mdadm only in the live cd)

Unfortunately, I was unable to install Kubuntu on the raid array because of another issue and filed a bug here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub-installer/+bug/1458788.

Comment: I know this is too late for you but this probably has the missing pieces http://askubuntu.com/questions/660023/how-to-install-ubuntu-14-04-64-bit-with-a-dual-boot-raid-1-partition-on-an-uefi]